# Edit CSS clip with JQuery, and use a set variable as one of the values

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var greenscale = 200 - (final_out * 2);
```

I have set a variable to be one of the values in the clip property.

How can I use that variable through this function:

```
$("#greenscale").css
        ("clip", );
```

I want the variable greenscale to change the bottom clip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! JQuery allows you to supply a function for the value argument of the .css() function.

So it'd look like this:

```
$("#greenscale").css
    ("clip", function(){
      return "rect(" + greenscale + "px," + "200px," + "200px," + "0px);"
});
```

You can find the documentation for it [right here](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function), it's been in since 1.4 and the idea behind it is that whatever your function evaluates to and returns is what will be used (so make sure you're outputting it as a valid CSS property value, since clip has some pretty stringent requirements as a CSS property)

Comment: So how would that look if I were to have the var greenscale value to be the top clip, and the right and bottom would be 200px and left would be 0px?

Comment: According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) clip is something like this: `clip:rect(0px,25px,25px,0px);` (top, right, bottom, left) it looks like it would evaluate with `return "rect(" + greenscale + "px," + "200px," + "200px," + "0);"`

Comment: Making sure it looks right so I keep editing it. I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: Alright. Yeah. Changed up some stuff, but in theory it should work!